# Redirect every incoming request to specific path preserving file and query?

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

As I'm not strong with apache could someone point me in right direction with this?

I currently have urls like this
`www.domain.com/public/my_file.php?query=thing&another=thing`

What I'm looking to do is to rewrite my code so i it don't use `/public/` part anymore, but after that i still need to support all crawlers and old urls people are linking to.

**So how would i do 301 redirect preserving everything that comes after `public/` part?**

(Example) Need to redirect something like this
`www.domain.com/public/my_file.php?query=thing&another=thing`
into this
 `www.domain.com/my_file.php?query=thing&another=thing`
with 301 redirect.

Thnaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Redirect 301 /public/my_file.php /my_file.php
```

The query string gets passed along by default.

---

EDIT:

To redirect everything in the public folder, use this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /public/(.*) /$1
```

Comment: sorry if i did not make it clear, but how do i do it for all request no just this 1 example?